# Convert NAD_1983_ALBERS to WGS 84

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

Recently I am working with US wetlands data, https://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/State-Downloads/NJ_shapefile_wetlands.zip

Data is in NAD_1983_ALBERS projection, and I want to transform it to lat/long using the `ST_Transform` function in Apache Spark/Apache Sedona. What is the right EPSG code for NAD_1983_ALBERS? I fiddled around with many but am not seeing the right results.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS loads in the NJ_Wetlands shapefile and recognises the .prj file as being NAD83/Conus Albers, or EPSG:5070.

Comment: This worked for shape files in New jersey , however it failed for hawaii and puerto rico shape files, do you have any recommendations. ?

Comment: What failed? I've just grabbed the HI_ version of the data and it seems to be fine. Can you edit your question to show what you are trying to do, and how it is failing - error messages etc?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use either [EPSG 42303 (Albers North America)](https://epsg.io/42303) or [EPSG 5070 (Albers CONUS)](https://epsg.io/5070). If you've got data with under 1 meter resolution there are some other slightly newer derivatives of 5070 that you might want to take a look at (see linked 5070 page).